# Getting datenum of predefined days, Matlab

Tags: matlab

I can get datenum of today

```
Daynum=datenum(fix(clock))
```

But how can I get it

1. yesterday
2. 7 days earlier
3. 6-11-2015

   I need all three above listed days. I know some of these are already integrated in new version but I don't have Matlab 2015.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) is:

> A serial date number represents the whole and fractional number of
>   days from a fixed, preset date (January 0, 0000).

So to get yesterday you could do:

```
Daynum_yesterday = datenum(fix(clock)) - 1;
```

And 7 days ago would be:

```
Daynum_7days = datenum(fix(clock)) - 7;
```

If you have a specific date you can already pass it to `datenum`, with an optional format specifier:

```
Daynum_mydate = datenum('6-11-2015');
% or
Daynum_mydate = datenum('6-11-2015', 'mm-dd-yyyy');
```

Which return the same result.

We can test all of these using [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html):

```
str_yesterday = datestr(Daynum_yesterday);
str_7days = datestr(Daynum_7days);
str_mydate = datestr(Daynum_mydate);
```

Which returns:

```
str_yesterday =

16-Nov-2015 07:44:41


str_7days =

10-Nov-2015 07:44:41


str_mydate =

11-Jun-2015
```

---

**Edit**: And an obligatory [*Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Time*](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time) citation.